# If checkbox is checked add new input box

Tags: html

I have a form like this

```
<form >             
   <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required id="fname" name="fname"/>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required id="lname" name="lname"/>

   <input type="checkbox" placeholder="Maiden Name" id="Maiden Name" name="chkname"/>

   <input type="hidden" placeholder="Maiden Name" id="mname" name="mname"/>
...
</form>
```

and if the checkbox is checked then the maiden name input box should be visible, can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Have you attempted the script yourself?

Comment: Where is your script please?

Comment: what script? I am asking you

Comment: @RemusRigo - You are asking us? You are the one who supposed to write the code...

Comment: I have a form and I've asked you how to show/hide a input box, but thanks to JoshC, I know now

Comment: Don't just edit your question like that, if you really want it deleted then flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance, it's possible to do this without JavaScript, just use the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked) pseudo class:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ3wR/)

```
#mname {
    display:none;
}
#maidenname:checked ~ #mname {
    display:block;
}
```

Use either the general sibling combinator, `~`, or the adjacent sibling combinator `+`, to change the display of the `input` element when the checkbox element is toggled. This of course assumes that the checkbox precedes the input element in the DOM.

---

If you would rather use JavaScript, you could use the following:

[**JS EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YF5xC/)

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('maidenname');
var input = document.getElementById('mname');

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (input.style.display != 'block') {
        input.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        input.style.display = '';
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if you would rather ***add*** an `input` element to the DOM (as your title implies), rather than changing the visibility of it, you could use something like this:

[**ALTERNATIVE JS EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VfnQD/)

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('maidenname');
checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('mn')) {
        document.getElementById('mn').remove();
    } else {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.id = 'mn';
        input.type = 'text';
        input.placeholder = 'Maiden Name';
        document.body.appendChild(input);
    }
});
```

Comment: but it does what I need

Answer (score 1):

you should not use maiden name input box as type="hidden". Use it as below:

```
 <input type="text" style=" display:none" placeholder="Maiden Name" id="mname" name="mname"/>
```

Call function to toggle display on click of checkbox:

```
<input onchange="showHideControl();" type="checkbox" placeholder="Maiden Name" id="Maiden Name" name="chkname"/>
```

Toggle maiden name input box:

```
function showHideControl()
   {
   $('#mname').toggle();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using pure javascript, like so:

```
<form id=frmMain name=frmMain>             
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required id="fname" name="fname"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required id="lname" name="lname"/>

<input type="checkbox" placeholder="Maiden Name" id="chkname" name="chkname" onclick=javascript:document.frmMain.mname.hidden=!document.frmMain.chkname.checked; />

<input type="input" hidden=true placeholder="Maiden Name" id="mname" name="mname"/>
...
</form>
```